# How to implement a Spring controller which returns any of multiple response types? (multiple 200 code responses)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, openapi

I have OpenAPI 3 documentation which defines a method:

```
  /header/somemethod:
    get:
      tags:
      - Layout
      summary: some text
      responses:
        200:
          description: success
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  anyOf:
                    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Item1'
                    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Item2'
```

How I can implement a Spring Boot controller which mathes this documentation?
How I can set up swagger annotations to generate this documentation?

I tried to generate a server in Swagger editor, but generated code doesn't show Item1 and Item2.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a way to do it in the controller ?

Answer (score -1):

I believe you have configured `pom.xml` file for swagger code generation. To get Item1 and Item2, you need to define them in the above file like below:

```
paths: # path definitions here    
definitions:
  Item1:
    properties:
      Item1_name:
        description: name 
        type: string
      Item1_value:
        description: value
        type: number
  Item2:
    properties:
      Item2_name:
        description: name 
        type: string
      Item2_value:
        description: value
        type: number
```

**Note:** Here fields in Item1 and Item2 are having fields *name* and *value*